# PHPMailer if else based on user's dropdown choice

Tags: php, phpmailer

PHP Rookie here...

Trying to put an if/elseif statement into my php code for a form email.

If user chooses "Sandy" then the email should go to Sandy's email address. If user chooses "Steve" send to Steve's email address, etc.  Here is the code I have so far.  Any advise is appreciated.

```
<?php

require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();

if( isset( $_POST['template-contactform-submit'] ) AND $_POST['template-contactform-submit'] == 'submit' ) {

if( $_POST['template-contactform-name'] != '' AND $_POST['template-contactform-email'] != '' AND $_POST['template-contactform-subject'] != '' AND $_POST['template-contactform-message'] != '' ) {

    $name = $_POST['template-contactform-name'];

    $email = $_POST['template-contactform-email'];

    $subject = $_POST['template-contactform-subject'];

    $message = $_POST['template-contactform-message'];

    $botcheck = $_POST['template-contactform-botcheck'];

    if( $_POST['template-contactform-employee'] = 'Sandy' ):

        {

        $toemail = 'sandy@example.com';

        $toname = 'Sandy';

        }


    elseif( $_POST['template-contactform-employee'] = 'Steve' ):

        {

        $toemail = 'steve@example.com';

        $toname = 'Steve';

        }

    elseif( $_POST['template-contactform-employee'] = 'Nick' ):

        {

        $toemail = 'nick@example.com';

        $toname = 'Nick';

        }

    else: {

        $toemail = "support@example.com";

        $toname = "Support";

        }

    endif;

    $body = "$message";

    if( $botcheck == '' ) {

        $mail->SetFrom( $email , $name );

        $mail->AddReplyTo( $email , $name );

        $mail->AddAddress( $toemail , $toname );

        $mail->Subject = $subject;

        $mail->MsgHTML( $body );

        $sendEmail = $mail->Send();

        if( $sendEmail == true ):

            echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>We have <strong>successfully</strong> received your Message and will get Back to you as soon as possible.</div>';

        else:

            echo '<div class="alert alert-error"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>Email <strong>could not</strong> be sent due to some Unexpected Error. Please Try Again later.<br /><br /><strong>Reason:</strong><br />' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '</div>';

        endif;

    } else {

        echo '<div class="alert alert-error"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>Bot <strong>Detected</strong>.! Clean yourself Botster.!</div>';

    }

} else {

    echo '<div class="alert alert-error"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>Please <strong>Fill up</strong> all the Fields and Try Again.</div>';

}

} else {

echo '<div class="alert alert-error"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>An <strong>unexpected error</strong> occured. Please Try Again later.</div>';

}

?>
```

Comment: Is there an issue with your code? Does it not work? If so, what's the error you're getting?

Comment: Page gives a success message that the message has been sent, but the email never arrives in the inbox. No error message.

Comment: What about if you take out the if/else statement, and hardwire your details in there; does it work in that case?

Comment: yes. i am modifying existing code.

Comment: Ah-ha! `if( $_POST['template-contactform-employee'] = 'Sandy')` is wrong - you're using `=` for an equality check, rather than `==`. Try `if( $_POST['template-contactform-employee'] == 'Sandy')`, and see if that makes a different (you'll need to amend each of the `if` lines.)

Comment: Changed.  Still No Joy

Comment: Alright. Can you put some debugging in? Echo something out in each `if` statement, to see which part is being called when it runs? And before you send the email, something to show the value to `$toemail` and `$toname`?

Comment: Ok, it echoes and post the data, it just isn't sending out the email.  Mind you, the original form and php still work so something in the code above is causing an issue.

Comment: working now. just got slammed with emails, so i believe the `==` fix worked. Everything was just stuck in the cloud... Thanks for all of your help. New to the forum, do I mark solved somehow?

Comment: you can submit your own answer, and accept that - just explain what the problem was and how you fixed it. Cheers, and thanks for letting me know you fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution from @andrewsi worked.  Thanks for spotting my error!

`if( $_POST['template-contactform-employee'] = 'Sandy')` is wrong - you're using `=` for an equality check, rather than `==`. Try `if( $_POST['template-contactform-employee'] == 'Sandy')`, and see if that makes a different (you'll need to amend each of the if lines.)